Cannot access internet through openVPN on certain IP pools
My setup currently is an Ubuntu 20.04 server running docker with an OpenVPN server inside a container, specifically this one.
Running with the default config:
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ip.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/ip.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
#route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"

allows me to connect to the VPN and to the internet just fine. However I went to change the IP pool since the network I will be connecting from is 192.168.0.0/16 and there will be potential IP clashes.
I changed the config to:
server 10.255.0.0 255.255.255.0 # The only line that has changed
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ip.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/ip.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
#route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"

but I can no longer connect to the internet. I can ping the gateway that the server creates, but trying to visit something like https://ipinfo.io doesn't work.
I have tried https://serverfault.com/questions/761857/changing-openvpn-dhcp-pool#761976 to no avail.
I don't know how to use the route option in the config and nothing I have read so far seems to have worked since I'm not trying to access machines behind the server, I'm just trying to get internet access.
Does anyone know what I might be missing here or anything that I need to add?
Thanks.
EDIT:
Below are the routing tables for the client device.
Before connecting:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1

After connecting (with '10.' configuration server side):
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.255.0.5      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
10.255.0.1      10.255.0.5      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.255.0.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
92.11.250.195   192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1


Are you trying to connect to the internet through the vpn, or separately? Can you edit your question to add the client's routing table?

@Cpt.Whale I am trying to access the internet through this connection. When connected successfully as mentioned above, my IP address changes when visiting something like https://ipinfo.io
Thanks
